# Ambiguous use of 'changeDetails(for:)'

Tags: swift

In my code, I met this error code:

> Ambiguous use of 'changeDetails(for:)'

Can you tell me how to fix it?

```
extension PHChange {
    func changeDetails<T: PHObject>(for object: T) -> PHObjectChangeDetails<T>? {
        return self.changeDetails(for: object) as! PHObjectChangeDetails<T>?
    }

    func changeDetails<T: PHObject>(for fetchResult: PHFetchResult<T>) -> PHFetchResultChangeDetails<T>? {
        return self.changeDetails(for: fetchResult)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already two functions inside the `Photos` framework that are doing the same stuff. If you'd still want to create the generic versions then you should change the external parameter name like so:

```
extension PHChange {
    func changeDetails<T: PHObject>(forObject object: T) -> PHObjectChangeDetails<T>? {
        return changeDetails(for: object) 
    }

    func changeDetails<T: PHObject>(forObject fetchResult: PHFetchResult<T>) -> PHFetchResultChangeDetails<T>? {
        return changeDetails(for: fetchResult)
    }
}
```